# index when serving 2 merged directories in nginx via try_files

Tags: nginx

I have two directories containing static files that I serve with nginx using the `try_files` directive. (One filled with generated pages by pelican, one with static content.)

However I can't get the `index` directive to work properly - I have to manually specify `index.html` when requesting an index page. How do I properly set that up so I can request `http://localhost/` instead of `http://localhost/index.html`?

Here's my configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name preview.mrwonko.de;
    index index.html;
    location / {
        root /;
        try_files /var/www$uri /home/willi/homepage/homepage/output$uri =404;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fine folks in #nginx on irc.freenode.org helped me figure it out, this is what worked in the end:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name preview.mrwonko.de;
    index.html;
    location / {
        root /var/www;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
    }
    location @fallback {
        root /home/willi/homepage/homepage/output;
    }
}
```